# Visual Studio 2019 - Move tab via keyboard

Tags: visual-studio-2015, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2019

In VSCode it's possible to reorder/move the select tab with a keyboard shortcut (`workbench.action.moveEditorLeftInGroup`).

But I can't figure out the name of the command to do this in VS2019.

Is it even possible in Visual Studio?

[image: Demo-Video]

Comment: Is there still no built-in way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can move tabs with my [Tabs Studio](https://tabsstudio.com/) extension. Assigning keyboard shortcuts to MoveTabLeft and MoveTabRight commands in the [Navigator add-in](https://tabsstudio.com/documentation/addins/navigator.html).

Comment: Weird this still doesn't exist by default - you can only seem to use Ctrl + Tab which doesn't swtich in tab order but instead by most frequent. Unfortunately that Tabs Studio extension you mention isn't free

Answer (score -1):

Oops, misread.

There are commands available to move to another document group (eg. `Window.MovetoNextTabGroup`), but likely not to rearrange within a tab group or to create another tab group.

It might be possible to add this functionality with an extension.

Note, often the order of tabs in a group is separately controlled – eg. the (sadly not supported in VS2019) Custom Document Well extension.

---

I don't think any keys are mapped by default, but I routinely remap <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>PageUp</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>PageDown</kbd> to `Window.PreviousTab` and `Window.NextTab` respectively.

Comment: These are the commands for *selecting*. I'm looking for the commands for *moving* the tabs. (for selecting, I'm using vim style alt+j / alt+k - i'm too lazy to move the right hand to reach the PageUp button)

Answer (score -1):

This is what I found from trying other attempts

1. Gather Confidence!
2. Visual Studio Search; 'Ctrl + Q'   a. type: "shortcuts"   b. select:
   {
   abbreviation: "and keyboard shortcuts",
   relevantHierarchyShown: [
   "Environment",
   "Keyboard"
   ]},   c. image:
   [image: VS Search & "shortcut" search term with auto suggestion]
   3. Find Window.NextTab & Window.PreviousTab   a. The current "Global" shortcuts for these are: [

   ```
   {
     command: "Window.NextTab", 
     shortcuts: [{
         shortcut: "Ctrl+Alt+PgDn",
         type: "Global"
       }],
   },
   {
     command: "Window.PreviousTab",
     shortcuts: [{
       shortcut: "Ctrl+Alt+PgUp",
       type: "Global"
     }],
   }
   ```

[image: visual studio: shortcut settings]

4. BrowserTab shortcut: Ctrl+PgDn & Ctrl+PgUp

   > a. This -according to the docs page w/shortcuts- is already a backup or alternate shortcut- though I did not see it in the dropdown as an existing shortcut for Window.NextTab|PreviousTab.

   > > a1. But when I tried to use it as a global shortcut: it doesn't appear to cut through other commands for 'page up'/'page down' when inside of the text editor    when I added the shorter shortcut from the browser;

   > b. 'Ctrl+{PgDn|PgUp}' vs 'Ctrl+Alt+{PgDn|PgUp}: I'm sticking with VisualStudio's Default of 'Ctrl+Alt+{PgDn|PgUp}' because:

   > > a. its only one extra key from the familiar browser shortcut.

   > > b. I also attempted to execute "Window.NextTabandAdtoSelection" with 'Ctrl+Alt+Shift+{PgDn|PgUp}'
   > > but didn't quite see that work- I figured it would select multiple
   > > tabs, but not sure

   > > i. link: [visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019)